# Correct build version to use Google API

Tags: android, google-api, build.gradle

I want to use `com.android.future.usb.UsbManager;` in my project. This class comes with google api. I created a new project and from the project structure settings ( I use android studio) I changed the compile SDK version to **Google APIs (API 19)** and the Build tool version to **19.1.0**

My build.gradle file is as following, but I get  couple of errors.

**My question is:** How can I find what's the correct combination to use Google APIs (API 19) or Google APIs (API 17)?
Which Build tools version (I tried all in UI)?

> Error:(9) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'."
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

```
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19'
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.cihan.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 5
    versionName "5.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

**Edit:** I reinstalled Android Studio and selected the latest Google API version and build version (both versions are now 24)

Comment: Why don't you use just the latest one?

Comment: max available value in gui is Google APIs (API 19) and max available build tool version is 24.0.3 if I select both max available values I get much more  errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'."

You need to compile the appcompat library

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19+'
}
```

**Note**: I only used version `19+` because that seems to be what you want to compile with. That was released in 2014, so I'd recommend upgrading.

You can compile using the latest SDK and still run (most) your code on devices on API 19

See - [**Android Material Design | Maintaining Compatibility**](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)

Comment: I changed build version to 24.0.3 ( max I can select in gui) and added compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
 but I still get same kind of errors. also I changed build.gradle like following       

compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cihan.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 5
        versionName "5.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: I don't think the buildToolsVersion should be greater than the compileSdkVersion. Same for the targetSdkVersion. If you cannot select a higher number, you need to install it from the SDK Manager

Comment: I will update now and try again. Can you please give me example one of your configuration. for example google API version buid version and this compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19+' attribute.

Comment: I unsinstalled Android Studio and reinstalled again.I select google api 24 and build vesion also 24 now it compiled successfully. Thank you very much for help